# "Object doesn't support property or method 'find'" in IE11 with Babel and Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, internet-explorer-11, babeljs

I'm getting some strange behavior in IE11 with use of Webpack and Babel. Currently, the issue is occurring is the following error message:

`SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'find'`

This only occurs in Internet Explorer, and strangely enough doesn't occur when running the code locally, only when it has been published.

```
const getColumnByName = (columns, columnName) => {   
    return columns.find((col) => col.Name === columnName);
}
```

Through the use of breakpoints, I can see that the code calls `columns.find` with an empty array 3 times, before it is passed an array of Objects. It is only on that 4th time that the error is thrown. In the IE console, I can run the following lines of code inside the above function to try to isolate the issue further.

```
Array.isArray(columns)
#=> true

Array.prototype.find
#=> function (predicate) { ...

[1,2,3].find(function(el){return el === 2})
#=> 2

columns.length
#=> 17

columns.find(function(e){return true})
#=> Object doesn't support property or method 'find'
```

All very strange to me.

Below is my webpack.config file, incase that helps.

```
/// <binding ProjectOpened='Watch - Development' />

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './Scripts/App.js',
    ],
  output: {
    filename: 'Scripts/ReactBundle/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.Webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js', '.jsx'],
    mainFields: ["main"]
  },
  module: {
      rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',               
            query:
                  {
                      presets: ['react', 'es2017', 'es2015', 'stage-2'],
                      plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
                  }
        },
      ]
  },  
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible `columns` could be a type [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) or something else that does not contain the `find` method but does contain the `length` property in a certain browser. Can you show us the part where you define the `columns` variable?

If so you can convert it to an array with `Array.from(columns);`.